# How can I assign the combination of possible values for some variables in R?

Tags: r, combinations

I am trying to do simulations with some variables changing their value in a range, is there a simpler way than creating a loop for each one of them?

This used to be my code on C++ (of course the loop was generated by another script so i could work faster)

```
 int SMA = 9; //extern
 double buyLotSize = .01; //extern
 double sellLotSize = .01; //extern
 int buySpreadMargin = 0; //extern
 double minEquity=.6; //extern
 int maxRisk=3000; //extern
 int FastMAPeriod = 12; //extern
 int SlowMAPeriod = 26; //extern
 double Lot=.01; //extern
 double lotLimit=.07; //extern
for(int SMA=3; SMA<33; SMA+=3)
for(double buyLotSize=0; buyLotSize<6; buyLotSize+=0.3)
for(double sellLotSize=0; sellLotSize<6; sellLotSize+=0.3)
for(int buySpreadMargin=0; buySpreadMargin<6; buySpreadMargin+=0.3)
for(double minEquity=0; minEquity<6; minEquity+=0.3)
for(int maxRisk=3000; maxRisk<60000; maxRisk+=3000)
for(int FastMAPeriod=3; FastMAPeriod<33; FastMAPeriod+=3)
for(int SlowMAPeriod=3; SlowMAPeriod<33; SlowMAPeriod+=3)
for(double Lot=0; Lot<6; Lot+=0.3)
for(double lotLimit=0; lotLimit<6; lotLimit+=0.3)
{   sim[nsim].SMA=SMA;
    sim[nsim].buyLotSize=buyLotSize;
    sim[nsim].sellLotSize=sellLotSize;
    sim[nsim].buySpreadMargin=buySpreadMargin;
    sim[nsim].minEquity=minEquity;
    sim[nsim].maxRisk=maxRisk;
    sim[nsim].FastMAPeriod=FastMAPeriod;
    sim[nsim].SlowMAPeriod=SlowMAPeriod;
    sim[nsim].Lot=Lot;
    sim[nsim].lotLimit=lotLimit;
    sim[nsim].dosomething() //start simulation
    ...
```

My plan is to to create a list with each variable value and range, but I am still too new to the language, and I cannot figure another way to use all the combinations without replcating the same loop, something like this would do the trick, I thought this kind of task would be simpler in R but I am not sure, I haven't found what I am looking for.

```
var1$range=range(min=0,max=3,step=.2)
var2$range=range(min=3,max=30,step=3)
for comb(var1,var2,...)
    dosomething(var1$value, var2$value) //simulation
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to do. Remember, though that using a loop for almost anything in R is a mistake. Perhaps you could look at the documentation for `expand.grid`.

Comment: ok, i have some variables which i want to have every possible value so I can use them on dosomething(), and have all the possible results.

Comment: How many combinations are there in total? You can probably do it with `expand.grid` if there's not zillions. eg generate your sequences and then `expand.grid(1:4,7:9,c("a","b","c"))` produces a data frame of all 36 (3*3*4) combos.

Comment: As mentioned above, `expand.grid` is exactly what you need. It takes a list of vectors and outputs a dataframe with all possible permutations.

Comment: A rough guess at your loop lengths suggests there are 11*18*18*18*18*20*10*10*18*18 = 748 BILLION combinations. I may be one or two out on each element. But even so, this is too big for `expand.grid`. If you really need to do this (HINT: You probably dont) then you need a way to incrementally generate combination N+1 from combination N.

Comment: @Spacedman thanks, I am thinking on adding just a few combinations because of the R performance just to check if do something is acting acordingly with the expected results. I need to make use of the variable names and not only accesing through indexes, is this possible with expand.grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`expand.grid` will return a data frame with all of the combinations of the input values. You would write a function that worked on a row of the data frame.

```
a <- seq(0, 1, 0.2)
b <- seq(0, 1, 0.5)

df <- expand.grid(a = a, b = b)

do_something <- function(a, b){
  #do something
  a + b
}

df$c <- do_something(df$a, df$b)

df
     a   b   c
1  0.0 0.0 0.0
2  0.2 0.0 0.2
3  0.4 0.0 0.4
4  0.6 0.0 0.6
5  0.8 0.0 0.8
6  1.0 0.0 1.0
7  0.0 0.5 0.5
8  0.2 0.5 0.7
9  0.4 0.5 0.9
10 0.6 0.5 1.1
11 0.8 0.5 1.3
12 1.0 0.5 1.5
13 0.0 1.0 1.0
14 0.2 1.0 1.2
15 0.4 1.0 1.4
16 0.6 1.0 1.6
17 0.8 1.0 1.8
18 1.0 1.0 2.0
```

Comment: Excellent man, thanks a lot I think this will do it. So far I love this language, it's very fancy.